# Adding custom columns into Firebase using React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I've successfully authenticated users information.  They can login and register without any problems, their information will be stored in `Firebase`.

But now, let's say a user with the email `abc@email.com` wants to choose an `Option` upon registering?.  How do I associate that `Option` with that user?  I tried looking this up for `React Native` but can't find any.

Here's `register.js`:

```
import firebase from '../config/firebase';
import home from './home.js';
import login from './login';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, Text, TextInput, AlertIOS, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import styles from '../theme/theme';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      email: '',
      password: '' 
    };
  }

  register(){
    var state = this;
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(function() {
      // Login successful.
      state.props.navigator.push({ component: home });
    }, function(error) {
      // An error happened.
      AlertIOS.alert(error.message)
    });
  }

  login(){
    this.props.navigator.push({ component: login });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, styles.center]} >
          <Text style={ styles.logo } >Register</Text>
        <TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            placeholder="Email"
            onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email: email})}
            value={this.state.email}/>
          <View style={styles.line} />
        <TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            placeholder="Password"
            secureTextEntry={true}
            onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password: password})}
            value={this.state.password}/>
          <View style={styles.line} />
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={this.register.bind(this)}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Submit</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.login.bind(this)}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Login</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Here's `home.js`:

```
import firebase from '../config/firebase';
import styles from '../theme/theme';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  test() {
    console.log("clicked!");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, styles.center]}>
        <Text>Choose a program</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Option one</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Option two</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Option three</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Option four</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: what kind of options do you want to give to user , can you explain it .

Comment: @ashutoshpandey It could be anything, fruits for example.  apples, oranges, bananas, kiwi.

Comment: that not the right place to that , see in the database , tab you can create those place in there.

Comment: Please don't post links in your question - use the actual textual data. I tried to access that link and it says 'over capacity'. Also, links break which can invalidate your question. If you want to (and should) include your Firebase structure,  you can get it from the Firebase Dashboard->Export JSON, and then copy and paste from the downloaded file. Oh, and Firebase doesn't have columns, only parent and child nodes.

Comment: @Jay Apologies for that.  How do I add parent and child nodes then?  I know it's possible to store more just than an email address.  How about something that can associate a user with one of the options?

Comment: With Firebase, each user you create is given a user id (uid). A typical design pattern is to create a /users node in your Firebase and within that node have child nodes with keys of each users uid. Inside each child node you can store whatever you want.  For example, if we wanted to store each users shoe size and option, it would look like this: users/uid_0/shoe_size: 10  and users/uid_0/option: option 1.